# How to convert HOC to react custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hoc

I have below code snippets, just wondering apart from passing a component to `withGroupInput`, do we have another way to re-use this `GroupedInputWithLabel` with different components? Thanks

```
export const GroupedInputWithLabel = (props) => {
  const { required, children, fieldName } = props;
  const inputComponent = (
    <>
      <ControlLabel htmlFor={fieldName} required={required} />
      {children}
    </>
  );
  return <GroupedInput {...props}>{inputComponent}</GroupedInput>;
};

export const withGroupInput = (props, Component) => (
  <GroupedInputWithLabel {...props}>
    <Component {...props} />
  </GroupedInputWithLabel>
);
```

Comment: `withGroupInput` is a component knw. Why do you need to convert that to a hook?

Comment: Sorry to make you confused, I mean to say react custom hooks to repeat this business logic instead of using HOC way.

Comment: yeah, that's what I also tell. You cannot convert components (return a JSX element) to a react hook

Comment: `withGroupInput` nor the `GroupedInputWithLabel` component contain any logic, what is there to convert? React hooks don't, and can't, replace React components. BTW, if you want `withGroupInput` to be a real HOC it's signature should look like `withGroupInput = Component => props => ( ..... )`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. May I please know apart from passing a component to withGroupInput do we have another way to re-use this GroupedInputWithLabel  with different components?

Comment: `GroupedInputWithLabel` ***is*** a React component, and designed to wrap other React components. It can be used with *any* component. Not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: You can send label as prop to the component and check if label is present than render it else render only the `<input>` tag.

Check could be like `{props.label && <span>{props.label}</span>}`